# What is the electric field due to a 1D line of charge on the edges of a pillbox geometry?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

The "[Introduction to Plasma Physics C17 Lecture Notes](http://people.physics.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdb112/courses/howard_plasma_C17/Howard_PlasmaC17_chap01.pdf)", which I'm reading online, set out the following scenario in section 1.1.2:

> Consider the electric field due to a 1-D line of charge (see Fig.
> 1.2). Applying Gauss' theorem to the pillbox shown, we find $$ \int E.ds = 2AE = \rho A dx/\epsilon_0$$

Here is the diagram:

[image]

I'm struggling to reconcile this with my understanding of Gauss' law. Looking at the above scenario I would say that the total charge $Q$ is equal to the charge density times the height, $A$ (area in 1 dimension). The total flux is the $E$ times the area at each side, so $2A$. Equating these via Gauss' law gives:

$$\Phi_E = 2AE = Q/\epsilon_0 = \rho A/\epsilon_0$$

This is not the same as the result in the lecture notes ($\rho A dx / \epsilon_0$). Why is the $dx$ relevant here? I have a suspicion that it's to do with my (mis)understanding of the geometry of a "Pillbox", but I'm not sure.

Comment: Note that your charge density appears to be per unit length, whilst the author's is per unit area.

Comment: @jacob1729 in the lecture notes the author says _$\rho$ is the charge per unit length of the line_.

Comment: If $\rho$ is charge per unit length then the author's expression $\rho A dx$ is not a charge. They must be interpreting $\rho$ as charge per unit volume (area).